# How to find registry keys for Windows Japanese Keyboard Settings?

Tags: c#, registry

I want to add Japanese keyboard for that i need to do specific settings for the keyboard. I want to find the registry keys for some of the settings like after installing the Japanese language there is option for

1. "Display Input mode at center of screen"
2. "Convert words and characters using JIS X 0208 characters "

I tried every link and every setting but am not able to get the registry keys for these settings , can anyone please suggest me how can i found the keys regarding these or any method to find for any setting would be helpful.

I have to do multiple settings for Japanese keyboards, have already found some of the registry keys on the link mentioned below but unable to find more registry keys for the specific settings.-
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927824/windows-may-not-use-the-correct-keyboard-layout-when-you-connect-a-usb

I want to know besides knowing answer to this question is there any specific way with which we can find the settings for any program of Windows through the registry keys.

Comment: Since this isn't a programming problem, I think that your question might be better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). Click [here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) to see what's considered "on topic" there.

Comment: This is the kind of things, programms should not even try to change. Wich Keyboard layouts should be enabeled should be a user-level decision. That means there is likely no API support. And without API support, you will likely be forced to at least log the user out and back in to have these changes apply. That is often what it takes to have the Explorer read in any changed registery values.

Comment: @Christopher am doing these changes as per the what the user will select on the UI and of course am restarting the system for the changes to be applied, it's that i have provided the broader overview for the problem.